# Are my fuchsias ok?

Tags: flowers, container-gardening

I have 2 fuchsia plants. I watered them with fertilizer mix and after that with normal water, every second day, they seem kind of dry but not completely when I water them. The pot is a hanging one with holes at the bottom, but not at the lowest parts

One has brown spots, and there's one dry flower with nothing brown on it. It fell off as soon as I touched it, but the brown and drying one is holding very strong. There are some buds browning too. Second one next to it looks without any problems like that. Is browning normal part of plant life or a problem? What should I do to keep them healthy?

I'm located in north part of Croatia for the climate.

[image: Fuchsia dry]
[image: Fuchsia brown]
[image: Fuchsia brown buds]
[image: Pots]

Comment: Are both fuchsias in the same pot? If so, it would have been good to see the pot with both plants,but a photo showing the pot and plant would be helpful anyway...has it been very hot or warm and dry where you are? Do the fuchsias receive sunlight?

Comment: @Bamboo They're in separate pots, I'll try to take a picture soon. It hasn't been too hot, hoodie weather mostly, it rained few times in last days and it's very windy. They're not directly in rain, but they do get wind. They get direct sun few hours in the morning. I'll wake up early tomorrow to get a measure of sun for the whole day to know exactly how much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look generally healthy; I think the browning flower was probably coming to the end of its bloom time, when they will gradually brown and fall off. Browning buds may mean they need watering daily, especially if they get a few hours sun in the mornings and the sun is hot (even if the air temperature is reasonably cool); Fuchsias prefer partial or dappled shade to grow well. They should be given a good watering when you do it, enough for water to run out of the tray at the bottom, so if you've not been doing that every other day, try that before you start watering daily, but the foliage does not look as if it's suffering drought, and there are plenty of healthy buds and flowers.

I'm not seeing brown spots on the foliage from either of your images, or did you mean brown flowers?

UPDATE:

If you're watering each one with 2-3 litres of water every other day, that should be adequate, so don't increase watering just yet. Feel the top of the soil on the second day to see if it's quite dry to the touch - if it's not then don't increase watering.

The browning buds could be due to very windy conditions, or very hot sun when you first planted because they were not used to it.  The other possibility is cold over night temperatures - both your fuchsias look to be tender varieties, and the buds will shrivel if it gets too cold. If it's really cold (frosty conditions) some of the leaves might brown too, but I imagine serious frosts on a regular basis are unlikely at this time of year where you are.

Comment: Flowers and buds are brown only, I was confused because the flower in first picture dried without getting brown, and there are buds that are brown before blooming. I'll try to water more, I gave them about 2/3-1L of water each time, once it dripped down, but other times not. It was too cloudy today to check exactly how much sun they get, but I don't think it's more than 2-3h in the morning. Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: oh, not 2-3L, 0.66 to 1L :D So I'll increase that a bit and check as you told me

Comment: Oh sorry, I read that as 2-3 litres and not two thirds of a litre!